# How to write text data unevaluated to google sheets cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheets Apps Script that uses this method to store data:
sheet.getRange(rowNumber, colNumber).setValue(theString);

Later, those values are retrieved using:
theRowData = sheet.getRange(r, FIRST_DATA_COLUMN, 1, MAX_COLS).getValues()[0];

This seems to be working fairly well except when theString contains a value that looks like a date (such as "6-Dec-2020". Then, getValues() seems to be retrieving a date value (and then converting it to a very verbose string) rather than the string that was written.  In this case, I do not want such evaluation of what the data means.  I intend to write these values as constants that don't need nor desire interpretation (such as would be done by apostrophe in Excel with a value like "'6-Dec-2020").  Is there a way to retrieve exactly the same value that was stored (or the store exactly the value that was intended), in exactly the same format?

For this specific problem example, I'm getting back "Sun Dec 06 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" when what I wrote (and what I want returned) is "6-Dec-2020" .  I do realize I could set number formats, but that won't always work, as these values (that admittedly look like dates) are sometimes in other formats, like "6-Dec" among others, and I would need "6-Dec" back when reading in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getDisplayValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue) or [`getDisplayValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues).

> The displayed value takes into account date, time and currency formatting formatting, including formats applied automatically by the spreadsheet's locale setting

Comment: Clearly that is so.  But the question is about how to avoid that.  Surely there is some way.

Comment: Oops, I misread - didn't see the "use getDisplayValue() ... " comment.  Excellent; solved my problem.  Thanks!